# ¿Es "a día de hoy" correcto?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras

Con frecuencia oigo o leo frases del tipo:

> **A día de hoy**, nadie me ha dicho nada.

Es decir, en lugar de decir solamente *hoy*, se enfatiza la palabra usando la coletilla *a día de*.

A mí me suena fatal pues resulta redundante y forzado, como si añadiendo estas palabras se consiguiera una formalidad añadida.

Sin embargo, me pregunto: ¿es correcto? ¿hay algún caso en el que su uso sea necesario o, al menos, dé contexto que *hoy* a secas no dé?

Comment: "*a(l) día de hoy*. Expresión innecesaria de estructura análoga al francés *aujourd’hui* (‘hoy’), que se ha puesto de moda en los últimos años en el lenguaje periodístico y político-administrativo. Se recomienda emplear en su lugar las locuciones o expresiones tradicionales hoy por *hoy, hasta hoy, hasta ahora, hasta este momento*, etc.; o, sencillamente, *hoy, en el día de hoy, hoy en día, ahora* o *en la actualidad*." ([DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=hoy))

Comment: Me da la misma idea que la frase en inglés, "Up until now, I haven't heard anything."  Como que aclara que no me ha dicho nada hasta este momento, pero no se puede declara que no habrá respuesta en dos hora, o en dos días....

Comment: en Colombia la expresión "al día de hoy" indica que algo que se esperaba sucediera o que dejara de suceder no ha cambiado su situación: por ejemplo "al día de hoy no han arreglado el hueco en la vía"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Me tomó mucho tiempo darme cuenta que en el francés la palabra aujourd'hui que en Español es simplemente "hoy", era la composición de "AU JOUR DE HUI (escrito correctamente aujourd'hui)" que sería en Español "al día de hoy". Siempre me ha dado curiosidad el estudio de otras lenguas romances y hemos copiado muchas expresiones no sólo del francés sino probablemente del latin vulgar.

En Perú la gente suele usar expresiones como HOY DÍA y los Colombianos suelen decir que para ellos es redundante y utilizan sólo HOY. Pero a mi parecer son modismos de cada cultura.

No obstante, la respuesta que encontré hace mucho tiempo atrás por la misma duda. Fuente: [Fundéu BBVA](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/a-dia-de-hoy-al-dia-de-hoy-304/)

> **A día de hoy** y **al día de hoy** son locuciones innecesarias tomadas del
>   francés que se emplean para expresar que un suceso determinado ocurre
>   en el mismo día o en la actualidad.
>
> En muchos medios de comunicación podemos encontrar frases como «La
>   Plataforma incorpora algunas de las tecnologías más populares a día de
>   hoy», «Un edificio que lleva bastante tiempo abandonado y que al día
>   de hoy se encuentra totalmente vacío» o «En España, a día de hoy,
>   harían falta más de 5000 camas especiales para atender problemas
>   geriátricos».
>
> Sin embargo, las expresiones a día de hoy y al día de hoy son un calco
>   del francés aujourd’hui (‘hoy’), por lo que, según se señala en el
>   Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, sería más recomendable usar
>   fórmulas equivalentes tradicionales del español, como hoy por hoy,
>   hasta hoy, hasta ahora, hasta este momento, etc., o, sencillamente,
>   hoy, en el día de hoy, hoy en día, ahora o en la actualidad.
>
> En los ejemplos anteriores, por tanto, hubiera sido preferible
>   escribir «La Plataforma incorpora algunas de las tecnologías más
>   populares hoy en día», «Un edificio que lleva bastante tiempo
>   abandonado y que hasta el momento/hoy por hoy se encuentra totalmente
>   vacío» y «En España, en la actualidad, harían falta más de 5000 camas
>   especiales para atender problemas geriátricos».

Aquí una definición que encontré recientemente de la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=CX0s2gwCdD6KHWZ68h)

> **hoy. <strike>a(l) día de hoy</strike>**. Expresión innecesaria de estructura análoga al
>   francés aujourd’hui (‘hoy’), que se ha puesto de moda en los últimos
>   años en el lenguaje periodístico y político-administrativo. Se
>   recomienda emplear en su lugar las locuciones o expresiones
>   tradicionales hoy por hoy, hasta hoy, hasta ahora, hasta este momento,
>   etc.; o, sencillamente, hoy, en el día de hoy, hoy en día, ahora o en
>   la actualidad, según los casos; así, en «El Atlético tampoco está a
>   día de hoy para dárselas de equipo grande» (País [Esp.] 21.4.97), pudo
>   decirse hoy por hoy o en estos momentos; y en «El futuro político del
>   país es probablemente al día de hoy el más incierto que ha visto en
>   muchísimos años» (Tribuna [Hond.] 24.5.97), se pudo decir,
>   simplemente, hoy. No debe confundirse la locución temporal
>   desaconsejada con el correcto uso de la secuencia al día de hoy: «Esa
>   simpatía se fue diluyendo hasta llegar al día de hoy, en que, si
>   hubiere elecciones, el PAN no alcanzaría ni siquiera el ansiado 4%»
>   (Hora [Guat.] 13.2.97).

Comment: soy colombiano y no concuerdo en que se considere redundante la expresión "al día de hoy"

Comment: No lo digo yo, me lo han dicho muchos Colombianos de Bogotá. Sin embargo, si no es el caso, me encantaría saber que tan frequente es usado es de donde vengas.

Answer (score -1):

Es una coletilla. Opino su empleo debería tender a cero. Algunas otras frecuentes: "la verdad" (y derivados), "es cierto que", "lo que", "si que", "un poco", "al final", "de alguna manera", "como" y "en plan" (estas dos ultimas más frecuentes entre jóvenes).

Comment: ¡Hola! Tu respuesta es similar a otras respuestas anteriores. Si estás de acuerdo con lo que dicen y quieres mostrar tu apoyo, lo mejor es votar esas respuestas y/o dejar un comentario, para evitar tener muchas respuestas iguales. Si lo que quieres es ampliar o mejorar la información o dar otro enfoque, considera [edit]ar tu respuesta para añadir una explicación, decir de qué forma se usa en tu zona, aportar elementos históricos, etc. Más info en [answer].

Comment: Si tal es el caso, añadiré algo: el empleo de coletillas es probablemente una manifestación más del carácter gremial de nuestra especie. El impulso por pertenecer al grupo nos lleva, en parte inconscientemente, a plagiar pautas de comportamiento y vestimenta. La forma de hablar, coletillas incluidas, es parte de ello. Su utilización nos asegura ser parte del grupo, ser uno más. Evitarlas, siendo posible, exige al menos vencer esta natural tendencia (no parece sencillo) y leer y buscar en fuentes seleccionadas y diferentes de las grupales. Confío la respuesta no sea ahora similar a otras.